# "Error: No space left on device" when booting ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, encryption, bug-reporting, debugging, debug

How would I repair the graphical OS from the terminal tty1?

I'm given the error:

```
Error: No space left on device.
```

Even though there is enough space.

Detailed description of the system:

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                  1.9G 400k 1.9G  1%   /dev
tmpfs                 384M 1.5M 382M  1%   /run
/dev/dm-1             454G 454G 0     100% /
none                  4.0k 0    4.0k  0%   /sys/fs/cgroup
none                  5.0M 0    5.0M  0%   /run/lock
none                  1.9G 4.0K 1.9G  1%   /run/shm
none                  100M 0    100M  0%   /run/user
overflow              1.0M 0    1.0M  0%   /tmp
/home/busylm/.Private 454G 454G 0     100% /home/busylm

df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed  IFree    IUse% Mounted on
udev                  485548   589    484959   1%    /dev
tmpfs                 490478   704    489774   1%    /run
/dev/dm-1             30220288 335692 29884596 2%    /
none                  490478   2      490476   1%    /sys/fs/cgroup
none                  490478   7      490471   1%    /run/lock
none                  490478   2      490476   1%    /run/shm
none                  490478   2      490476   1%    /run/user
overflow              490478   4      490474   1%    /tmp
/home/busylm/.Private 30220288 335692 29884596 2%    /home/passkart
```

Comment: Please update your qoestin with the output of `df -h` and `df -i`

Comment: "Even though there is enough space." how is 100% used "enough space"? :-) I would examine what ate your 454G. That's a lot of wikipedia pages :-P

Comment: How would you find the source of the extra usage ?

Comment: What is this `/home/busylm/.Private 454G 454G 0     100% /home/busylm` ?

Comment: @SorenA They appear when you encrpyt your $HOME.